# VBA Insert new row and data from user form into another sheet table each time clicks macro button

Tags: excel, vba

I have a manual made form(text fields) that uses vlookup to return those fields correspondant values, based on unique ID typed.
Example:
ID : 0001 (static number)
Type : vlookup value1
Price : vlookup value 2
Owner: vlookp value 3
And another table that just need that ID to be inserted each time in the first table row called "ID",
Example:
row1 "ID"
the other columns rows are returned with a vlookup call formula.

But what i need is that each time i type new value in the form Id field(from sheet 1 the form) and i hit the Insert macro button; VBA to compare that user typed "id" to the ids found in the table "ID" column rows(sheet2) and if that ID typed is not found; to insert new line with same above format and insert the new ID into the first row in that new line; also to check another row value in the table(called : Type , placed in separate line alone) and compare to another user form field(called : Type) value (from sheet 1 just like the ID stuff..) and if it's different values then to copy the same line format and paste the new type field 's value , then execute the first step and insert ID in new line below the "new "type" line).
Actually i started with that code but it's not checking or pasting new lines below the first one or giving an error if i use `Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlDown` for example.

```
Sub add_item()
'
' add_item Macro
'

'
  Sheets("AJOUTER_PV").Select
  Range("K6").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Inventaire").Select
    Range("A5502").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
  If Sheets("AJOUTER_PV").Range("K6").value <> Sheets("Inventaire").Range("A5502").value Then
  
   Range("A5577:AF5577").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Insert , CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("A5502").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=3
    Range("A5502:AL5502").Select
    Selection.Copy
   
    Range("A5577:AL5577").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlDown

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
End Sub
```

*Where  Range("K6") is the Id field from user form.

Range("A5502") is the Id field from the table where the id is going to be inserted first time in "A5502" then "A5503" etc.

**before each line of the table, there is the "Type"line (in a separate merged to one cell line), and here where we need to check types from both user and table to know if we need to insert new type line with the new data from the user form, and then insert new line with the "ID" value from the user form same formatting (+ formulas) as the ID line with the pre-made vlookup auto completed rows using "ID" reference.
[image: THE FORM]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps some answer is better than no answer. If it isn't I apologize.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Add_Item()

    ' declare all variables
    Dim WsPV        As Worksheet                ' Sheets("AJOUTER_PV")
    Dim WsInv       As Worksheet                ' Sheets("Inventaire")
    Dim Id          As Variant                  ' referenced ID
    
    ' assign values / objects to the declared variables
    Set WsPV = Worksheets("AJOUTER_PV")
    Set WsInv = Worksheets("Inventaire")
    
    ' use the Cells collection to address cells
    ' syntax is Cells([Row number], [Column number or name])
    Id = WsPV.Cells(6, "K").Value
    WsInv.Cells(5502, "A").Value = Id
    ' you could also use:- WsInv.Cells(5502, "A").Value = WsPV.Cells(6, "K").Value
    
    '  What 's this? You just made A5502 = K6!
    ' If Sheets("AJOUTER_PV").Range("K6").Value <> Sheets("Inventaire").Range("A5502").Value Then
  
    ' not clear what you intend, either from your code or you text
    ' so, here is some syntax you might adapt
    WsPV.Rows(5577).EntireRow.Insert CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    WsPV.Range("A5502:AL5502").Copy Destination:=WsInv.Cells(5502, "B")
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

The outstanding message of the above is that you don't need to `Select` anything. Instead, you should address the objects (worksheets, ranges, cells) and modify their properties (only their `Value` property is touched here). In order to address them you should declare variables and assign values and objects to them. In order not to leave anyone out you should specify `Option Explicit` at the top of the code sheet.

Comment: Am working on your code , it's fairly good enough at least adding Id into the second sheet first row; but not inserting new row and the if bloc not working correctly...

Comment: Please note the need to take into account that the if bloc needs to add new line and data each time Id in sheet one is different with id in last line first row in sheet 2 so that  data is not copying over in same line or next line for example.Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Updated version of code(rebuilded table "Inventaire" so actual cells are like in the updated code ... but the problem with this code that actually i don't need that a cell keep equal to another but need a sequence of copy paste each time in a new row underneath "CBR" column when the code is executed.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Add_Item()

    ' declare all variables
    Dim WsPV        As Worksheet                ' Sheets("AJOUTER_PV")
    Dim WsInv       As Worksheet                ' Sheets("Inventaire")
    Dim Id          As Variant                  ' referenced CBR
    
    ' assign values / objects to the declared variables
    Set WsPV = Worksheets("AJOUTER_PV")
    Set WsInv = Worksheets("Inventaire")
    
    ' use the Cells collection to address cells
    ' syntax is Cells([Row number], [Column number or name])
    Id = WsPV.Cells(6, "K").Value
    WsInv.Cells(4, "A").Value = Id
    ' you could also use:- WsInv.Cells(5502, "A").Value = WsPV.Cells(6, "K").Value
    
    '  What 's this? You just made A5502 = K6!
     If Sheets("AJOUTER_PV").Range("K6").Value <> Sheets("Inventaire").Range("A4").Value Then
   WsPV.Rows(5).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    WsPV.Rows(5).EntireRow.Insert CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    ElseIf Sheets("AJOUTER_PV").Range("K6").Value = Sheets("Inventaire").Range("A4").Value Then
    ' not clear what you intend, either from your code or you text
    ' so, here is some syntax you might adapt
   
    
    WsInv.Range("A4:H4").Copy Destination:=WsInv.Cells(5, "A")
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
End Sub
```

> So before adding the new line , this code is always copying the same
> value to first row then add the new value to the second line which gives always only 2 lines and duplicate data..